# how to retrieve one row of many selected rows

Tags: mysql

I would like to select multi col across multi table in order to display them as only one row in MYSQL

like this example:

```
     ___________
    |uId|xID|yID| 
    |_1_|_2_|_4_|
```

Into

```
 ___
|zId|
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 4 |
```

here is the query but col t returns null data beside all of the selected cols

```
SELECT `flaghsip_leader`,`clustuer_coordinator_id`,`clustuer_cocoordinator_id`,
    `flagship_activity_coleader_id`,`flagship_activity_focalpoint_id`,
    `output_leader_id`,`output_coleader_id` AS `t` 
FROM crpcoreix.view_all_involved_users;
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? It is not entirely clear what you want to achieve. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: merge the above three cols values as one col

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described, I think you'll need to use multiple select queries and join them with UNION ALL.

e.g.

```
SELECT uId as zId from Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT xId as zId from Table2
UNION ALL
SELECT zId from Table3
```

Comment: sounds good but why we dont add the "as zId" after selecting all the cols without union ? like this

Comment: If I remember correctly, MySQL will throw an error if you try and merge columns with different names using UNION.

Comment: @Ambulare MySQL doesn't care about the column names in the 2nd+ subqueries in `UNION`. You only need `AS` in the first subquery.